# Borel and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I fail to see how this Borel set is **an element** of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

The Borel Set:

$$
\{1\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-1/n,1] = \mathbb{R}\setminus \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}\setminus (1-1/n,1]\right)
$$

I've attempted to use these definitions to see if the Borel set is an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra but i haven't had any luck :(

> **Defintion:** A family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $\Omega$ is said to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ if:
>
> (A.1) $\Omega\in\mathcal F$
>
> (A.2) $\ A\in\mathcal F\implies\ A^c\in\mathcal F$
>
> (A.3) $\ A_1,A_2,...\in\mathcal F\implies\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal F$
>
> **Definition**:
>
> The *Borel $\sigma$-algebra* on $\mathbb R$ is the *$\sigma$-algebra* B($\mathbb R$) generated by the $\pi$-system $\mathcal J$ of intervals (a, b], where a < b in $\mathbb R$ (We also allow the possibility that a = $-\infty$ or b =$\infty$) Its elements are called *Borel sets*.
>   For A $\in$ B($\mathbb R$), the $\sigma$-algebra
>
> B(A)= {B $\subseteq$ A: B $\in$B($\mathbb R$)}
>   of Borel subsets of A is termed the *Borel* $\sigma$-algebra on A.

Comment: I think what you are supposed to show here is that the set $\{1\}$ is **an element** of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. A single set is not a $\sigma$-algebra!

Comment: Why would you ask whether $\{1\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra? Who or what gave you the idea that it might be?

Comment: @David K Excuse me, that is none of your concern, edits have been made. I obviously have a few misconceptions and blanks in my understanding of the subject. That is why I am here.

Comment: Based on edits it seems you came up with the notion yourself, which is fine. Indeed that is how one learns. If the notion had come from somewhere _else_, though, it might have some implications on what you need to do (e.g. if it was written in exactly those words on a homework assignment). That is why I asked.

Comment: Further, you can generate the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ with $ \{ \; \{ x \} \; | \; x \in \mathbb{R} \} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\text B(\mathbb R)$,
the interval $I_n=(1-1/n,1]$ is contained in $\text B(\mathbb R)$ for every $n$.
Thus,
according to clause (A.2),
so is their complements $I_n^c=(-\infty,1-1/n]\cup(1,\infty).$
Then,
according to clause (A.3),
you know that the union of the complements $I_n^c$ is also in $\text B(\mathbb R)$.

Hint: at this point, you can use [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for unions and clause (A.2) again to obtain the desired result.